# OnClickListener on CustomDialog from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, textview, customdialog

I've a customDialog class and I call it in a different fragment.
I want to create the `onClick` function in this fragment, but my click don't do anything.
The custom dialog code :

```
public enum SwipeType {LIKE, NOPE}
private SwipeType swipeType;
private Record swipeRecord;

public NewsfeedDialogBox(Context paramContext, SwipeType type, Record record) {
    super(paramContext);
    this.mContext = paramContext;
    this.swipeType = type;
    this.swipeRecord = record;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.newsfeed_dialog_layout);
    preferences = PreferenceDatabase.getInstance(mContext);
    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setupBox();
}

private void setupBox() {
    swipeYesButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    swipeNoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    if (swipeType == SwipeType.LIKE) {
        swipeBoxTitle.setText(R.string.swipe_love_title);
        swipeBoxLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_icon);
    } else {
        swipeBoxTitle.setText(R.string.swipe_nope_title);
        swipeBoxLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.cross_close);
    }
    String url = "";
    int loader = 0;
    if (swipeRecord instanceof Track) {
        url = "http:" + ((Track) swipeRecord).getAlbum().getThumbnailUrl();
        loader = R.drawable.music_load;
    } else if (swipeRecord instanceof Album) {
        url = "http:" + ((Album) swipeRecord).getThumbnailUrl();
        loader = R.drawable.music_load;
    } else if (swipeRecord instanceof Playlist) {
        url = "http:" + ((Playlist) swipeRecord).getThumbnailUrl();
        loader = R.drawable.music_load;
    } else if (swipeRecord instanceof Image) {
        url = "http:" + ((Image) swipeRecord).getBestImageUrl();
        loader = R.drawable.image_load;
    } else if (swipeRecord instanceof Video) {
        url = "http:" + ((Video) swipeRecord).getThumbnailUrl();
        loader = R.drawable.video_load;
    } else if (swipeRecord instanceof Movie) {
        url = "http:" + ((Movie) swipeRecord).getThumbnailUrl();
        loader = R.drawable.movie_load;
    }
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(url)
            .config(Utils.getBitmapConfig(mContext))
            .error(loader)
            .placeholder(loader)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(swipeBoxBackground);
}
```

My fragment code :

```
public void firstLike(Record record) {
    if (!PreferenceDatabase.getInstance(getContext()).isSwipeLikeDone()) {
        newsfeedDialogBox = new NewsfeedDialogBox(getContext(), NewsfeedDialogBox.SwipeType.LIKE,record);
        newsfeedDialogBox.show();
        Button yesButton = (Button)newsfeedDialogBox.findViewById(R.id.swipe_yes_button);
        yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newsfeedDialogBox.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my CustomDialog
[image: Custom Dialog]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is.

Comment: where are you using firstLike() method

Comment: @KastriotDreshaj a big thx you, i'm a retard.
I've two method firstLike and firstNope (swipe Left / swipe right) since the begining i swipped left all the time, so the firstLike wasnt called.
Thx you ;)